# WPF ListView does not get updated when changing item DisplayMemberPath MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have WPF ListView which bind to ObservableCollection.

Here is my ListView:

```
<ListView 
                BorderBrush="#6797c8" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainCategoriesCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Category" 
                SelectedValuePath="MainCatID" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding MainCategorySelectedItem}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding MainCategorySelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                FontSize="14"/>
```

and this is my ItemSource:

```
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel.MainCategories> mainCategoriesCollection;
public ObservableCollection<DataModel.MainCategories> MainCategoriesCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (mainCategoriesCollection == null)
        {
            mainCategoriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataModel.MainCategories>();
        }
        return mainCategoriesCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        mainCategoriesCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MainCategoriesCollection" );
    }
}
```

I have wired problem. When I add items or delete item from MainCategoriesCollection my ListView get updated without any problem but when I take specific item and change the item property which represent "DisplayMemberPath" I can`t see the change in the ListView. I debugged the problem and saw that the change is exists in MainCategoriesCollection but my ListView refuse to show it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The best way to debug binding problems usually is just to look for binding errors in output window of Visual Studio

Comment: No need to INPC your observable collection property.

Comment: Will the binding still update without INPC if you instantiate a new ObservableCollection?

Comment: Will right, ObservableCollection already contain INPC so I don`t had to implement it manually.

Comment: Indeed, the collection will notify. The question is unrelated to your code, so sorry for hijacking. @Will Tested this and the binding won't update if you instantiate a new `ObservableCollection` without putting INPC on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure the DisplayMemberPath property is on a view model with all the INotifyPropertyChanged stuff, i.e. is the property observable?